# @return annotation for a chaining enabling method in PHP

Tags: php, annotations

A class should enable chaining on setters, so the respective functions should `return $this;`

Now for the `@return`annotation i saw implementations with

`@return self`

and

`@return MyModel`

Which one is regarded best-practice and why?

Comment: Personally, I'd always identify the actual object type being returned rather than simply self: that way, there can be no ambiguity. However, can be slightly awkward if that return is in a parent class because it can't identify the actual child class that was instantiated and is being returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some IDEs do not support @return self, thats why some devs use @return MyModel

If you have some method in 'ParentClass' class.

case 1) @return ParentClass. When you call the method from child, actual returned object is different from the documented.

case 2) @return this. Everything is OK

same for @return MyModel vs @return self/static

Comment: ok so with `self` and `ParentClass` you have the Problem and with `this` you don't? Is support of `this` better than `self` across IDEs?

Comment: `this` should be used in non-static methods. `Self/static` should be used in static methods